# Using templates for polymorphism

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, design-patterns

So I've got some compile time polymorphism in some legacy code. i.e

I have a base class to use that takes in a template parameter.

```
template<typename HANDLER>
class Base
{
  virtual HANDLER * make_handler();
  // other methods
};
```

`make_handler` constructs the HANDLER using a specific constructor that takes in two arguments (important later).

The handler is generally the only thing we need to change for code sharing that does a single method `std::size_t handle_data(const char *, std::size_t length);` which is the entry point

```
class SpecificHandler
{
  SpecificHandler(uint32_t id, uint32_t source_id);
  std::size_t handle_data(const char *, std::size_t length);
  // other methods
};
```

That we use by

```
class Child : public Base<SpecificHandler>
{
  // other overridden methods
};
```

The problem I have is that I would like to pass in another parameter in my SpecificHandler class i.e.

```
class OtherSpecificHandler
{
  OtherSpecificHandler(uint32_t id, uint32_t source_id, uint32_t other_id);
};
```

unfortunately the Base class calls the two argument constructor in the template.

The work around I have at the moment is to override the `make_handler()` call to return the handler created with the 3 argument constructor i.e.

```
class Child : public Base<OtherSpecificHandler>
{
  virtual OtherSpecificHandler * make_handler();
  // other overridden methods
};
```

Unfortunately because the template stuff is done at compile time I have to still provide the 2 argument constructor, (in fact I just provided a default argument for the third argument), which feels wrong.

Normally I would solve this problem using dependency injection with a pointer for the Handler rather than using templates, but this is used in a lot of places and I would rather not change it.

What are my other options?

Thanks

Comment: Can you make changes to `Base`?

Comment: I can, but I would rather not if it can be helped. For instance I'm not even considering changing from template to normal polymorphism in the Base class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing that comes to mind is making the base class method pure virtual:

```
template<typename HANDLER>
class Base
{
  virtual HANDLER * make_handler() = 0;
  //other stuff
};
```

That would of course mean that *every* derived class has to overload `make_handler`, even if every other handler class has the same two-argument constructor. To avoid the repetition in that, insert another layer into the hierarchy:

```
template<typename HANDLER>
class BaseWithStandardHandlerConstruction : public Base<Handler>
{
  virtual HANDLER * make_handler() override //maybe final as well?
  {
    return new HANDLER("meow", 4);
  }
  //that's it - nothing else goes here...
};
```

Then any class with a "normal" handler derives from the latter, while classes with "special" handlers derive from the former:

```
class Child : public BaseWithStandardHandlerConstruction<SpecificHandler>
{
  // other overridden methods, no make_handler needed
};

class OtherChild : public Base<OtherSpecificHandler>
{
  virtual OtherSpecificHandler * make_handler() override;
  // other overridden methods
};
```

Comment: I did think of making it pure virtual but I didn't think about the extra layer, that could be quite nice. Thanks.

Comment: @oracal I just noticed I missed a vital part in the code: Of course, `BaseWithStandardHandlerConstruction` has to derive from `Base`.

Answer (score 1):

You may template specialize `Base`

Something like

```
template <>
OtherSpecificHandler* Base<OtherSpecificHandler>::make_handler() {
    return new OtherSpecificHandler(42, 5, 12); // With correct parameter ofc.
}
```

Comment: I did actually try this and couldn't get it to compile. Maybe I should give it another shot. Thanks.

Comment: So it turns out that the reason that I couldn't do this is because the  new thing I need to pass in is a member in the child class.

Comment: You may return `nullptr` so (maybe a `throw` if appropriate), and just use the virtual derived implementation. But it seems that Arne Mertz's answer is more appropriate in your case.